# APPLICATION WILL TERMINATE IS NOT WORKING IN Below Case

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

> I m facing big problem With Application Termination State.In My app
>   need to Satisfied   Following Points.....
>
> 1)Application Is in Back Ground Switch To Fore Ground (no Need To
>   Store Data)
>
> 2)Application Is Background After Some Time If User Go to home And
>   Terminate Application (need To Store Data)
>
> **is there any delegate method Will Call Before Application
>   Terminate .** `- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication
>   *)application`
>
> Is not Working With Because In 1 Case Application Running So
>   Suspended When We Try to Terminate Application.
>
> Please Help me Out From This Issue..... If Any Ideas Also Would Be
>   Appropriated

Comment: Can't understand your question. Rephrase your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should always store your data when going into the background (`applicationDidEnterBackground:`). There is no guarantee that you will receive any further opportunities prior to being terminated.

Comment: your are absolute Right But in my case its not possible.y because ...i m displaying all current downloads With respect to state From Database .if I Restore The Data when its back ground Then If I terminate App no Issues  .if i coning To back To Foreground it should Continue The Previous State (ie is When Its In Back Ground)

Comment: Then you'll have to rethink your design. Your title implies that applicationWillTerminate isn't working, when in fact it is working exactly how it says it will.

Comment: When you go into the background, you must assume that you may not come back before being terminated. You will have to design in such as way as to handle this. You may have to write your data to a temporary location for instance, and check for that when you re-enter the foreground.

Answer (score 2):

This is how it's supposed to work. This is what it [says in the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786):

> For applications that support background execution, this method is
>   generally not called when the user quits the application because the
>   application simply moves to the background in that case

If there is data that you need to save, you should do it when the app goes into the background.

Comment: your are absolute Right But in my case its not possible.y because ...i m displaying all current downloads With respect to state From Database .if I Restore The Data when its back ground Then If I terminate App no Issues .if i coning To back To Foreground it should Continue The Previous State (ie is When Its In Back Ground)

Comment: You'll just have to store the intermediate state when your app goes into the background. If you don't, as you've found, you stand to lose _all_ non-saved data. This is just the way it works. You could raise a bug report with Apple, but I wouldn't hold your breath for a change.

Answer (score 1):

No there is nothing called, because your app killed by the OS, this could also happen if the system need more free memory.

You should save the data when every your app gets send to the background, not when it gets terminated.

Comment: your are absolute Right But in my case its not possible.y because ...i m displaying all current downloads With respect to state From Database .if I Restore The Data when its back ground Then If I terminate App no Issues .if i coning To back To Foreground it should Continue The Previous State (ie is When Its In Back Ground)